# Boost log trivial auto flush

Tags: boost, boost-log

In default mode boost.log writes to the console, which is fine by me.  I'm trying to force it to auto-flush as well, however.  All examples dealing with auto flush I can find show how to add a new sink, which seems unnecessary in my case.  There is no method to get existing sinks via boost::log::core.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default sink is intended to be used as a fallback of last resort and cannot be customized directly. Once you add a sink, the default sink will no longer be used. To log to the console with auto flushing enabled, one can use [`add_console_log`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/boost/log/add_console_lo_idp64470384.html).

```
boost::log::add_console_log(boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true);
```

Comment: Ended up doing this: 

"boost::log::add_console_log(std::cout, boost::log::keywords::auto_flush = true);" - works for me, thanks :)